# Approach to secure different WebApi service methods for different clients

Tags: asp.net-web-api, authorize

I have a set of services, all of which have, up until now, served a single client. The service methods so far have fallen into two groups - those that are secured/require a token and those that are accessible to anyone. The secured methods have the `[Authorize]` attribute assigned to them and the non-secured methods do not. It all works fine. We're using an Identity Server-based Authentication service and bearer token authentication.

Now I want to add a new client and one or two new methods that are only accessible to that new client. Defining the new client in my Authentication service is easy enough. I want to understand how best to authorize different methods for different clients. Do I need to build my own custom Authorize attribute that checks either the client id or, better yet, the scope and define a separate scope for these new methods?

I guess that's the bottom line question: Does authorizing different methods for different clients entail a custom Authorize attribute? Is that the typical or best approach or is there another way?

Comment: Are you using standard .NET, or .NET Core?

Comment: I am using .NET Standard.